# Why does a mesh size change after parenting to another mesh in three js?

Tags: three.js

I have added a mesh (item) to another mesh (forearm) using `forearm.add(item)`. Once added, the mesh `item` becomes very tiny.

But according to console.log() the scale of the item remains the same before and after `add` operation.

Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: What scale of the `forearm`?

Comment: Scale is depending on parent item, if the forearm scale.set(100,100,100), forearm.append(item) will scale item to (item.scale.x*forearm.scale.x,..,..)